# next day doesn't work using setDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Try to let user click next and prev button to adjust date using JS.

This doesn't work when I plus one day and try to get tomorrow's date.

```
$('#next_date').click(function(e) {
  var get_selected_date = "2015-12-14",
  nextDay = get_selected_date.split('-')[2] + 1,
  selectedDate = new Date(get_selected_date),
  date = new Date(selectedDate.setDate(nextDay));
  console.log(date);
});
```

But I manage to get previous date using the same logic, just minus one day like below

```
$('#prev_date').click(function(e) {
  var get_selected_date = "2015-12-14",
  nextDay = get_selected_date.split('-')[2] + 1,
  selectedDate = new Date(get_selected_date),
  date = new Date(selectedDate.setDate(nextDay));
  console.log(date);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with the date being a string and by adding one you append to the string - the 1 is turned to a string instead of the 14 being turned into an integer. Subtracting from a string coerces the string to a number, however. This is one of JavaScript's quirks and comes from reusing operators. Since the plus sign is also used to combine strings, its behaviour with mixed type operands is somewhat confusing.

Small cheatsheet (assuming string can be coerced to a number):

```
string + string = string
string + number = string
number + string = string
string - number = number
number - string = number
string - string = number
+string + number = number (read below)
```

You can either parse the string you get from `get_selected_date.split('-')[2]` to an int using `parseInt(str)` or use the common workaround prepending the string with a plus sign. This coerces the string into a number. So your code only needs this change:

```
nextDay = +get_selected_date.split('-')[2] + 1
```

---

For optimization you might also want to write

```
selectedDate.setDate(nextDay);
```

and use that selectedDate instead of your

```
date = new Date(selectedDate.setDate(nextDay));
```

setDate() returns but it also works in-place, so it changes the date you use it on.

On a sidenote: please use var for all variables. Otherwise they're global and will mess with your other code.

Comment: why this doesn't happen for the previous day?

Comment: @Jennifer: Because the `-` operator does not have a double meaning, as does `+` (which is the mathematical addition operator as well as the string concatenation operator.)

Comment: Thx @CBroe Just added more details on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = '2015-12-14';
    str = str.split(/\D+/);
    str = new Date(str[0], str[1] - 1, (parseInt(str[2]) + 1));
```

str will return '2015-12-15'

// str[2] is date, str[2]) + 1 is add one day

for prev date,
str = new Date(str[0], str[1] - 1, (parseInt(str[2]) - 1));

str will return '2015-12-13'